# Highcharts: How can I find out which which legend items are disabled?

Tags: highcharts

I want to recreate the legend in my own div, I followed another SO answer which gave this example this:

> ```
>         events: {
>             load: function () {
>                 var chart = this;
>                 $(chart.series).each(function (i, serie) {
>                     $('<li style="color: ' + serie.color + '">' + serie.name + '</li>').click(function () {
>                         serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
>                     }).appendTo('#legend');
>                 });
>             }
>         }
> ```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3xvg/1/

You will notice unlike the original chart, the a legend item does not grey out (or change) if I click on it.

What property can I check/interrogate (elegantly?) to find out which which legend items are disabled?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS class and add to item.

```
 $(chart.series).each(function (i, serie) {
                    $('<li style="color: ' + serie.color + '">' + serie.name + '</li>').click(function () {
                        if(serie.visible) {
                            $(this).addClass('inactive');
                            serie.hide();
                        } else { $(this).removeClass('inactive');
                            serie.show();
                        }

                    }).appendTo('#legend');
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3xvg/16/